# how can i use a dataset for refinement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2000

how can dataset filtering be done?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? what does your database model look like, how are you populating the dataset? what do you want to filter?

Comment: i just want to filter the results contained in dataset....
dataset contain various fields from which i have to filter the results for specific value of columns.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking filtering dataset table rows:

```
myDataSet.DefaultViewManager.DataViewSettings["myTableName"].RowFilter = "ID = 3";
```